# How to get the height of the layout in the onCreate method or out of that so that the childs are set again?

Tags: android, layout, height, android-edittext

Ofcourse I know it returns 0 measures until it is drawn to window. But I need to get the height of the layout and accordingly the child views should get adjusted. Below is my code snippet.In this class I am generating 36 edittexts using adapter class. So I need to get the height of the layout according to the screen to adjust the edittexts. Screen height would not be helpful for my app. Any code snippet would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class GameView extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    FrameLayout frameLayout1;

    GridView gridView;

    EditText et[][]=new EditText[6][6];

    TextAdapter textadapter;


       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


              setContentView(R.layout.gamedisplay);

              frameLayout1=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fLayout1);

              int layoutHeight = frameLayout1.getMeasuredHeight();//this is I need. So according to this I make adustments to edittexts.
              Log.d("tag"," height :: " + layoutHeight);
              System.out.println("In gameview >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   "+layoutHeight);
              gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

              gridView.setAdapter(new TextAdapter(this));

              //gridView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

              WindowManager wm=getWindowManager();
              Display display=wm.getDefaultDisplay();
              int gridSize = display.getWidth();
              int colWidth = (gridSize / 6);
              gridView.setColumnWidth(colWidth);





             // getEditTexts();
             // putValues();


           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only going to be able to pre-measure things if you have hardcoded dimensions in your XML. For example, in your XML if you have something like `android:layout_height="20dp"`, then you can use something like:

```
Resources r = getResources();
float layoutHeight = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, r.getDisplayMetrics());
```

If you're using wrap_content or match_parent, then by definition those things are calculated relative to how things are laid out on the screen and getting these dimensions prior to them being laid out is murky at best.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what's the use of getting hardcoded dimensions in program when we already know them. It doesn't work for app.

Comment: Well, the benefit of this is that you can lay it out properly for the benefit of the "average" screen, but you can still adjust things in runtime if the phone has some weird dimensions or something... This allows you to at least find the dimensions on the device it's running on, which is why this takes the displaymetrics into the calculation of the dimension.

Comment: In my experience, this is most useful for scaling custom views while maintaining an aspect ratio where the width/height of the view is purely dependent on how much screen space is available.